# Android Design : How to run 3 different threads in Background for monitoring 3 different devices

Tags: android, multithreading, service, intentservice

I have an application, where I want to monitor 3 Bluetooth devices for their status from the Android Phone. For this, I need to send some data to each device and check if their response is correct every 5 seconds. And I want this processing to happen even when the application is not in Foreground. I thought of different solutions But I could not come up with any good solution.

- I thought of using IntentService. But IntentService uses one thread for doing all the processing. But I would like 3 different threads because 5 seconds between every check is low that I cannot hop between checking devices in a single thread.
- I thought of using 3 different IntentServices. But Not sure, if its the best way to go ?
- I thought of using a Service and spawning of 3 threads, one foreach device. But I was not sure if these threads will run when the app is not in foreground.

  What would be the best design to run this sort of app which does background processing in a app even when the app is not in Foreground and it has to run 3 different threads.

Answer (score 2):

One Service, three Threads is what you want. Having a single thread performing I/O on multiple devices just seems like asking for problems, its creating a dependencies that are unnecessary. All Threads execute, regardless of whether the app is foreground or background.

The Android framework doesn't have any way to stop a Thread from running. Thread execution is managed by Dalvik. The framework stops delivering events to an app's main Thread when its in the background (other than events like BroadcastIntents), but it doesn't tell Dalvik to pause all threads in that process. This would kind of defeat the purpose of background processing if it did.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need three threads. You definitely need three BluetoothSocket s. You might be able to pull it off just by having one Service that starts a thread from onStartCommand() and kills it in onDestroy(). The thread should loop and check if there is an active connection to each device, and if there isn't one, it should attempt to reconnect. Once a connection is established, it should write to and then read from the device, according to its protocol. There is nothing stopping you from writing/reading to multiple devices in the same thread. You can use nonblocking IO for this, checking whether there are bytes to read on each iteration until you find them, and then taking an action based on what you receive.

As far as pairing/bonding goes, I would do that outside of the thread that checks the devices, as you might want to direct the user to enter the pin/pair the device. Just make the background thread read/write to each of the three devices. You may find that you want multiple threads, it's purely a matter of taste... Only one thread is needed.

Comment: I designed it too in the same way initially. But then I got into an issue, where I am trying to reconnect with one device and since it blocks, the tracking of other 2 devices dont happen at that time. And the read and write are blocking according to BluetoothSocket documentation.  Another doubt, I have is , IF i create a thread from a service, will it run even after the app goes into background.